# Как распаковать последовательность букв и чисел в строку?

Tags: python

Мне с помощью кода нужно превратить из `A3b4` => `AAAbbbb`.
Это был мой простой пример, но в задании ввод гораздо больше.

Вот пример моего кода:

```
i = 0
my_letters = []
my_numbers = []
numbers = '0123456789'
letters = 'qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm'
up_letters = 'QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM' 
with open(r"dataset_3363_2 (1).txt") as s:
    for row in s:
        opened_string = row 
        for i in range(len(opened_string) - 1):
            if opened_string[i] in letters or opened_string[i] in up_letters:
                my_letters.append(opened_string[i])
            elif opened_string[i] in numbers:
                my_numbers.append(opened_string[i])
                if opened_string[i+1] in numbers:
                    my_numbers[i].append(opened_string[i + 1])
        print(my_letters)
        print(my_numbers)
    s.close()
```

В `dataset_3363_2 (1).txt` читается

> "q20j13h11Z6N8v7z17E12U4L1u2P18c10J17B4j2W5H20m20u8U10D4k18T15u9h12"

Главная моя проблема - когда код записал в отдельный список букву, а потом считывает цифру, он находит лишь ОДНУ цифру, а мне может пригодится число 15, а мой код считает это как 1 и 5.

Главная моя задумка -  найти буквы, и записать их в список, потом найти цифры, и записать их в другой список. А потом умножать букву `my_letter[i] * my_numbers[i]` (i = 0 а потом увеличивается на одну единицу)

Если же я плохо смог объяснить, то вот [оригинал задания](https://stepik.org/lesson/3363/step/2?auth=login&unit=1135).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

В принципе, вы выбрали верный подход к решению задачи. Если не использовать регулярные выражения и следовать вашему алгоритму, то сделать можно так:

```
a = "q20j13h11Z6N8v7z17E12U4L1u2P18c10J17B4j2W5H20m20u8U10D4k18T15u9h12"

#получаем два списка - один с буквами, другой с числами, но в обратном порядке
def separate(a: str):
    letters = []
    muls = []
    while a:
        head = a.rstrip('0123456789')
        tail = a[len(head):]
        muls.append(tail)
        letters.append(head[-1])
        a = head[:-1]
    return (letters, muls)

# перемножаем список с буквами на список с числами в соответствующих позициях
def mult(letters:list, muls:list):
    res =""
    for i in range(len(letters)):
        res+=letters[i]*int(muls[i])
    return res[::-1] # переворачиваем строку в нужном порядке

letters, muls = separate(a)
#print(letters)
#['h', 'u', 'T', 'k', 'D', 'U', 'u', 'm', 'H', 'W', 'j', 'B', 'J', 'c', 'P', 'u', 'L', 'U', 'E', 'z', 'v', 'N', 'Z', 'h', 'j', 'q']
#print(muls)
#['12', '9', '15', '18', '4', '10', '8', '20', '20', '5', '2', '4', '17', '10', '18', '2', '1', '4', '12', '17', '7', '8', '6', '11', '13', '20']
result = mult(letters, muls)
print(result)
```

> qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqjjjjjjjjjjjjjhhhhhhhhhhhZZZZZZNNNNNNNNvvvvvvvzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzEEEEEEEEEEEEUUUULuuPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPccccccccccJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJBBBBjjWWWWWHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmuuuuuuuuUUUUUUUUUUDDDDkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTuuuuuuuuuhhhhhhhhhhhh

Если я не ошибаюсь, это решение будет быстрее, чем решение с использованием регулярных выражений и с проверками isalpha/isnumeric. Причем, ощутимо быстрее.

Answer (score 8):

Воспользуйтесь регулярными выражениями:

```
import re

def unpack(s):
    res = ""
    for x in re.findall(r"(\w)(\d+)", s):
        res += x[0] * int(x[1])
    return res
```

однострочник:

```
res = "".join([c * int(n) for c,n in re.findall(r"(\w)(\d+)", s)])
```

Comment: Однострочник вообще сделать и совсем красота ))

Comment: @CrazyElf, добавил однострочник )

Answer (score 4):

Решение на "Vanilla Python":

```
def unpack(s):
    res = ""
    curr_c = ""
    n = 0
    for i,c in enumerate(s):
        if c.isalpha():
            curr_c = c
            n = 0
        elif c.isdigit():
            n = n*10 + int(c)
            if i == len(s)-1 or not s[i+1].isdigit():
                res += curr_c * n
    return res
```

Тесты:

```
In [80]: unpack("A10b4")
Out[80]: 'AAAAAAAAAAbbbb'

In [81]: unpack("A1B2")
Out[81]: 'ABB'
```

Answer (score 4):

Если использовать регулярки, то можно через замену `re.sub` еще в одну строку

```
import re

text = "q20j13h11Z6N8v7z17E12U4L1u2P18c10J17B4j2W5H20m20u8U10D4k18T15u9h12"

print(re.sub('(\D)(\d+)', lambda x: x.group(1) * int(x.group(2)), text))
```

Answer (score 0):

Асимптотически минимальное решение:

````
    a = "q20j13h11Z6N8v7z17E12U4L1u2P18c10J17B4j2W5H20m20u8U10D4k18T15u9h12"
    s = ''
    d = 0
    cur_s = ''
    def is_digit(s):
        for i in '0123456789':
            if i == s:
                return True
        return False
    
    for i in range(len(a)):
        if is_digit(a[i]):
            d*=10
            d+=int(a[i])
        else:
            s+= cur_s*d
            d=0
            cur_s = a[i]
    s+=cur_s*d
    print(s)```
````